# Dropdown option in QGIS 3 processing modeler input?

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

I have an Excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets of different XY database. I made a processing model in QGIS 3.10, in which I have used `'make points from table'` tool to create a point shapefile.

But in my Excel spreadsheet, there are multiple sheets so I can only select the first sheet as an `'input'`. So, how can I make a dropdown option to select any sheet from input Excel?